# Fixed Output sequence for selectOutput5

Tags: anylogic

Problem statement:
I want to experiment with different sequences for the routing through the selectOutput5 block.

Example:

Random (all 5 Outputs can be choosen by probability 0.2) (thats the easy part that i solved)

Fixed: (Output1: 6 agents, after those six agents, Output2: six agents and so on...
Do you have an idea on how i can do this based on expressions or conditions?

Thank you very much and have a great weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "Use:" property in your SelectOutput5 block to "Exit number". Then you can define which exit to use.

For your example, I would create an int type variable named `currExit` and set the initial value to 1. Set the value of "Exit number [1..5]:" in your SelectOutput5 block to `currExit` and write this code to the "On enter:" property:

```
if (self.in.count()%6==0) {
    currExit++;
    if (currExit>5) currExit=1;
}
```

This switches to the next exit for every 6th agent (`self.in.count()` returns the number of agents that have entered the block so far).